# Time and Calendar

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

How do I add/subtract two time objects. I have two time objects (arrival and departure) in format of "yyyy/MMM/dd HH:mm:ss". I need to print the difference between departure and arrival time. I am generating time ad below:

```
public String getTime() {
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    return formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
}
```

Can I get time in mills and than format it when I needed to print ?

Comment: As a side note, it is non-trivial to get the (non-millisecond) durations between two dates (as milliseconds) - it is dependant on time of year and timezone (this is, of course, mostly to deal with daylight savings time).  The relevant code needs to figure out the year/month/day/etc. for _both_ dates, then deal with _those_ figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this.....

```
public long getTimeDiff() throws Exception {
    String arrival = "2011/Nov/10 13:15:24";
    String departure = "2011/Jan/10 13:15:24";

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/dd HH:mm:ss");

    java.util.Date date1 = formatter.parse(arrival);
    java.util.Date date2 = formatter.parse(departure);

    return date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library.

You can easily subtract and add DateTime and find out interval easily :

```
// interval from start to end
DateTime start = new DateTime(2004, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2005, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert them to date and then to long and subtract, that would give the time difference in milli seconds,

```
Date d1 = DateFormat.parse(time1);
Date d2 = DateFormat.parse(time2);
long diffInMilliSeconds = d1.getTime()-d2.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get time in milliseconds for both calendars using getTime method. When you can convert the result of subtraction to measure units that you need. If you're going to work with time/duration seriously when take a look at Joda library

Upd. You should call getTime twice. First object being returned is Date, when you call getTime on Date you get long value.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the two time/Date objects in milliseconds. Then i would subtract them (we are dealing with longs).

Then i would create a Date object from the resulting long value. After that you can construct a Calendar with Calendar.setDate(Date).

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, start with your Dates and use `getTime()` to convert to milliseconds (or `getTimeInMillis()` for your Calendars). That give you long values you can subtract. That's the easy part.

Then you can convert these milliseconds into a readable format yourself. But it probably makes sense to use a packaged library to do it.

Some folks like the Joda library for these types of date calculations. I find [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) is fantastic. It provides `DateUtils` which is useful if you find you want to perform calculations like rounding or truncating your dates to the nearest minute or hour etc. The part that will be most useful to you is the `DurationFormatUtils` class which gives you functions like `formatDurationHMS` to format into nice Hour:Minute:Second display and `formatDurationWords` to get text (fancy!) or other similar functions to easily format your milliseconds into a nicely human-readable format.